# How to select alternating values from a list, to convert to datetime?

Tags: python, list, datetime

I'm currently learning about string methods. However, I have run into this issue where I get a ValueError.

I have a list of lists named `result_list` in which the first index of the row is a date/time stamp and the second index is the number of comments. I've been asked to do the following:

- Extract the hour from the date, which is the first element of the row.
- Use the `datetime.strptime()` method to parse the date and create a datetime object.

```py
from datetime import datetime

# here is your list of values
result_list = ['8/16/2016 9:55', '6.0', '11/22/2015 13:43', '29.0']

# set the format
date_format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'

for row in result_list:
    time = row[0]
    time_dt = datetime.strptime(time, date_format)
```

### Error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ecf5afb3f99e> in <module>
      9 for row in result_list:
     10     time = row[0]
---> 11     time_dt = datetime.strptime(time, date_format)

e:\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    566     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    567     format string."""
--> 568     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    569     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    570     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

e:\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    347     found = format_regex.match(data_string)
    348     if not found:
--> 349         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
    350                          (data_string, format))
    351     if len(data_string) != found.end():

ValueError: time data '8' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
```

I assume I am getting the error due to the `datetime.strptime()` constructor expecting a value of 08 instead of 8. However, I'm unsure of where to start in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `result_list` is a flat list, there are no groups, so `row[0]` is the `8`, from the value at index 0.
- Once the date value is correctly converted to a datetime, use the various methods, such as `.hour`, to extract the required value.
- One option is to use a list-comprehension to group the date and associated comment count.

```py
from datetime import datetime

# here is your list of values
result_list = ['8/16/2016 9:55', '6.0', '11/22/2015 13:43', '29.0']

# set the format
date_format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'

# group each date and count together
rl_updated1 = [result_list[k:k+2] for k in range(0, len(result_list), 2)]

print(rl_updated1)
[out]:
[['8/16/2016 9:55', '6.0'], ['11/22/2015 13:43', '29.0']]

# convert to a datetime format in a list comprehension
rl_updated2 = [[datetime.strptime(v[0], date_format), v[1]] for v in rl_updated1]

print(rl_updated2)
[out]:
[[datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 16, 9, 55), '6.0'],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 22, 13, 43), '29.0']]

# alternatively, iterate through rl_updated1, before converting to a date format
for group in rl_updated1:
    dt = group[0]
    dt = datetime.striptime(dt, date_format)
```

- Keep the flat list, and select dates from indices where `i % 2 == 0`

```py
for i, v in enumerate(result_list):
    if i%2 == 0:
        time_dt = datetime.strptime(v, date_format)
        print(time_dt)
    else:
        comment = v
        print(v)

[out]:
2016-08-16 09:55:00
6.0
2015-11-22 13:43:00
29.0
```